# Check if session factory has an active session or not

Tags: hibernate, session, jakarta-ee

I would like to check if a SessionFactory object has an active session or not and if it is bound to a thread. getCurrentSession creates a new one if there is no session, but I just want to know if there is a session, not to create if one does not exist, kind of like request.getSession(false) in HTTPSession. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. Hibernate SessionFactoryImpl uses an interface for session management named "CurrentSessionContext". Every implementor uses different methods to manage the current session. So you may write some code with reflection api to reach the internal state of your specific implementation but it is so cumbersome. But there is no direct way.